# How to send ESC Commands from android application?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am developing android application and need to send ESC command to cut paper after printing.

1) Please guide me how to send ESC commands from android.

2) And What command is used for paper cutting after printing.

Answer (score 2):

Solution that i came up with:

```
Socket sock;
PrintWriter oStream;
DataInputStream is;

sock = new Socket(ip, port);
is = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

oStream.println(new char[]{0x1D, 0x56, 0x41, 0x10}); // 0x1D, 0x56, 0x41 is for paper cut and 0x10 is for line feed.

oStream.flush();
oStream.close();
sock.close();
```

Comment: Works great for me, but can you tell me what does "line feed" mean? Thank you so much.